# How to mass update recurring date rules?

Tags: 7, rules, datetime, views

I would like users to be able to mass update recurring date rules possibly using VBO and Rule sets.

For example: user would like to add "exclude date = 01/01/2012" recurring date rule for all selected nodes' dates where date is a new field added to a content type.

How to do this ?

---=EDIT=---

I have already build a basic Rule with the following code:

```
{ "rules_change_end_date_for_selected_content" : {
    "LABEL" : "Change end date for selected content(s) (Test rule)",
    "PLUGIN" : "rule",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : {
      "node" : { "label" : "Content", "type" : "node" },
      "event_end_date" : { "label" : "Event End Date", "type" : "date" }
    },
    "IF" : [
      { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "node" ], "field" : "field_event_date" } },
      { "node_is_of_type" : { "node" : [ "node" ], "type" : { "value" : { "event" : "event" } } } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "node:field-event-date:0:value2" ],
          "value" : [ "event-end-date" ]
        }
      },
      { "entity_save" : { "data" : [ "node" ] } }
    ]
  }
}
```

What should I put instead of `node:field-event-date:0:value2` to modify the date rule end date ( not the first date enddate). I would like to change the date until this node repeats but I cannot see tokens for the date repeating rule.

Comment: I created feature request for rrule tokens for Date module http://drupal.org/node/1613842

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it will need a custom module, However have you tried the bulk update module?, you could extend this and adapt it for dates, I do not have any code examples, as it does sound quite complex.

Comment: This probably require patch to Date module date.tokens.inc to allow rrule tokens. Please see http://drupal.org/node/1613842

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Date Repeat Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/date_repeat_entity) module. Module features, see item 2 specifically for your needs:

> - Attach unique content to each date in a recurring series
> - Update current, future or all recurring dates
> - Delete current, future or all recurring dates
> - Configuration per bundle (content type)
> - Provides warnings when updates may affect referenced content
> - Includes hooks for additional control of what gets repeated and when

I personally just started using this module, it's fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the crucial part of a working rule is a [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) Action to perform a **Loop** (to replace your first Rules Action to "Set a data value"). If you're not familiar with such loops, then I strongly recommend to have a look at the tutorial titled "[Lists and loops](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/lists-and-loops)".

In your case, you should use (at least) have a Rules Action to create a loop related to your `node:field-event-date` field (as shown in the rule included in your question). After you do, you should iterate over each item in that list. And for each iteration you should then perform a Rules Action to "Set a data value for the list item being processed in the loop", and set that value to your Rules Component parameter `event_end_date`.

***Done***

PS: Refer to my answer to "[How to set multiple values to an unlimited Term Refence field with Rules](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/220892/how-to-set-multiple-values-to-an-unlimited-term-refence-field-with-rules/220894#220894)" for some sample rules that are like a variation of your question here.