# How to set a term reference field value from a text field with Rules?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, rules

In the user entity, there are 2 fields: a single-valued field_department_text A (a text field) and a multi-valued term reference field_department B.
Now, I need to use Rules to append A's value to B when a user was created. I tried, but failed.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you could just use the "add to list" Rules Action.

For multi value fields you should not use "Set a data value" (which is possibly what you've tried, a common mistake when using Rules for such fields).

Refer to the answer to "[How to set multiple values to an unlimited Term Refence field with Rules](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/220892/how-to-set-multiple-values-to-an-unlimited-term-refence-field-with-rules/220894#220894)" for "some" more details ...

Comment: In fact, I used the "Add an item to a list" action, so I used the word "append". The problem is that the text field A can not be set as the datasource for the term reference field B.