# How to unpublish a node and any related nodes?

Tags: 7, nodes, rules

I am currently working on a problem where, when a *Physician* node has been unpublished, its related *Review* nodes will be unpublished as well. They do have an entity reference built in to distinguish which *Review* belongs to which *Physician*.

I have been working with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), [Views Bulk Operations (VBO)](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations), and [Workflow](https://www.drupal.org/project/workflow) modules to get this to work.
I have many failed attempts using the Rules module, so I don't have any code to supply.

Would anyone be able to point me in a direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this seems perfectly possible with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) ... In your case, the crucial part of such rule is a Rules Action to perform a **Loop**. If you're not familiar with such loops, then I strongly recommend to have a look at the tutorial titled "[Lists and loops](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/lists-and-loops)".

In your case, you should use (at least) have a Rules Action to create a loop related to your '*related "Review" nodes*' (as in your question). After you do, you should iterate over each item in that list. And for each iteration you should then perform a Rules Action to "unpublish the review being processed in the loop".

***Done***

PS 1: Refer to my answer to "[How to set multiple values to an unlimited Term Refence field with Rules](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/220892/how-to-set-multiple-values-to-an-unlimited-term-refence-field-with-rules/220894#220894)" for some sample rules that are like a variation of your question here.

PS 2: I assume this is about D7 ...

Comment: Thank you for the great direction! I will give this a go for sure. And yes this is D7, definitely should have added that.

Comment: Excellent! Got the appropriate tag on there and checked your response as the best answer.

Comment: @NickGordon: merci for the "accept", and the update of your question ... PS: if you have additional questions later on about all this: get back to here!