# Rule fetches only single taxonomy term from multiselect values

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms, rules

I have created a Rule which is supposed to fetch all the selected term from a taxonomy term field (a field that holds a list of taxonomy terms). But when the rule is executed, it fetches only one taxonomy term instead of all. The field is set to hold "unlimited" values.

**Rule is:**

```
Entity type = taxonomy term
Condition => content-type = course
Data selector => node:field-autodealer:name
```

The rule is supposed to add all users from selected groups into a course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you included n your question (with "Rule is"), does nto really look like a rule to me, rather something that is part of your rule. However, since you're trying to process a multi value field, a crucial part of a working rule is a [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) Action to perform a **Loop**. If you're not familiar with such loops, then I strongly recommend to have a look at the tutorial titled "[Lists and loops](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/lists-and-loops)".

In your case, you should (at least) have a Rules Action to create a loop related to your field *that holds the list of taxonomy terms*. After you do, you should iterate over each item in that list. And for each iteration you should then perform the desired Rules Actions.

***Done***

PS: Refer to my answer to "[How to set multiple values to an unlimited Term Refence field with Rules](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/220892/how-to-set-multiple-values-to-an-unlimited-term-refence-field-with-rules/220894#220894)" for some sample rules that are like a variation of your question here.

Comment: Thank you so much. I followed the same approach to fix the issue. Used variables and loop.